# Are firestore transactions re-executed when the doc to be updated is removed?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Imagine this db structure:

```
/users(collection)
   userId/ (doc)
      likes/ (collection)
         postId1 (doc)
         postId2 (doc)
```

I am implementing a function for liking/disliking posts.

For that, I am running a transaction where I `get` the like status (isLiked) using the transaction, in order to do this (like) or that (dislike).

When a like operation is performed, I need to add the liked post to the `likes` sub-collection of the user that gave the like.

But... what if the document of the user (that is liking the post) is deleted (in the UI I have a section for user profile deletions) during the like operation?

If I just do:

```
transaction.create(`users/${userId}/likes/${postId}`, denormalizedPostData);
```

will the removal of the user doc be detected by the transaction?

If not, what if I also delete the likes/ subcollection of the user when deleting its doc?

```
deleteUserDoc(userDocRef);
deleteFullCollection(userLikesRef, batchSize);
```

Will the

```
transaction.create(`users/${userId}/likes/${postId}`, data);
```

detect the "change" (the deletion of the doc) and re-execute the transaction?

I am asking this because I know that we need to make sure that reads are situated before writes in the body of transactions, in order to re-execute the transaction if the read docs change... but, what about this situation?

**I am afraid of re-creating the user doc** because of just attaching a doc to the user likes collection using the `transaction.create()` operation.

---

Should I make an extra read in the top of the transaction?

```
transaction.get(userRef); // Just to ensure the re-execution
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the document the transaction handler and then write modification to it in that same handler, then the Firestore SDK sends the pre-transaction state and post-transaction state of that document to the server. This allows the server to then detect whether the document was modified during the transaction, including whether it was deleted.

Comment: I do not feel very comfortable adding that extra read in the transaction, since, I do not use the data read in the handler, and also, the read document is updated quite frequently by several users, and in some occasions that would produce repetitions of the transaction and therefore, extra costs (and more probability that things fail (imagine massive updates to that document in a short period, during the transaction execution)).

Comment: BTW, I have realized that it is a quite extreme case but that it could happen, leaving some orphan document the execution of the transaction logic (for not having read the status of the document (to notice the elimination)). Is this a normal situation in NoSQL?

If not, in transactions should we read all erasable documents that may alter the state of our logic for a certain function? Still without having to use the data from these documents?

Comment: If your transaction handler doesn't read the document, the server won't be able to detect that the document was deleted. There is no way to detect that situation without reading the document that you want the database to check on.